# Delay and de-duplication using Reactive Extensions (Rx)

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I want to use Reactive Extensions to transform some messages and relay them after a small delay.

The messages look something like this:

```
class InMsg
{
   int GroupId { get; set; }
   int Delay { get; set; }
   string Content { get; set; }
}
```

The output looks something like this:

```
class OutMsg
{ 
   int GroupId { get; set; }
   string Content { get; set; }
   OutMsg(InMsg in)
   {
       GroupId = in.GroupId;
       Content = Transform(in.Content);  // function omitted
   }
}
```

There are a couple of requirements:

- The length of the delay is dependent on the content of the message.
- Each message has a GroupId
- If a newer message comes in with the same GroupId as a delayed message awaiting transmission then the first message should be dropped and only the second one transmitted after a new delay period.

Given an Observable<InMsg> and a Send function:

```
IObservable<InMsg> inMsgs = ...;

void Send(OutMsg o)
{
     ... // publishes transformed messages
}
```

I understand that I can use Select to perform the transformation.

```
void SetUp()
{
     inMsgs.Select(i => new OutMsg(i)).Subscribe(Send);
}
```

- How can I apply a message specify delay? (Note this might/should result in out of order delivery of messages.)
- How can I de-dupe messages with the same GroupId?
- Is Rx capable of solving this problem?
- Is there another way of solving this?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `GroupBy` to make an `IGroupedObservable`, `Delay` to delay the output, and `Switch` to make sure newer values replace previous values in their group:

```
IObservable<InMsg> inMessages;

inMessages
    .GroupBy(msg => msg.GroupId)
    .Select(group =>
        {
            return group.Select(groupMsg => 
                {
                    TimeSpan delay = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(groupMsg.Delay);
                    OutMsg outMsg = new OutMsg(); // map InMsg -> OutMsg here

                    return Observable.Return(outMsg).Delay(delay);
                })
                .Switch();
        })
        .Subscribe(outMsg => Console.Write("OutMsg received"));
```

A note on the implementation: if a grouped value arrived *after* the message is sent (ie. after the delay), it will start a new delay

Comment: I've had a play with this and it doesn't quite do what I'd expect.  The subscription receives a "System.Collections.Generic.AnonymousObservable`1[OutMsg]"

Comment: It sounds like you're not calling `Switch`. If you "mouse over" `Select` in Visual Studio it should tell you that it returns an `IObservable<OutMsg>`. If it returns `IObservable<IObservable<OutMsg>>`, you're not calling Switch

Answer (score 2):

@Richard Szalay's answer *almost* works for me (using .NET Rx 3.1.1 on .NET Framework 4.6), but I have to add `.Merge()` to the end of the expression to combine the `IObservable<IObservable<OutMsg>>` results, like so:

For me (using .NET Rx 3.1.1 on .NET Framework 4.6) the fix was to add `.Merge()` to the end, like so:

```
var deduplicated = inputs
    .GroupBy(input => input)
    .Select(group =>
        group
        .Select(input => Observable.Return(input).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)))
        .Switch())
    .Merge(); // <-- This is added to combine the partitioned results
```